# Read Keyvault secrets from DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-keyvault, vnet

Trying to read Key Vault from DevOps pipeline.  After granting Service Connection access to Key Vault, still getting below error while reading Key Vault secrets from DevOps

```
Downloading secrets using: https://xx-xx-xx-kv-sit.vault.azure.net/secrets?maxresults=25&api-version=2016-10-01. 
##[error] Get secrets failed. 
Error: Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service. 
Client address: xx.xx.x1.1xx
```

[image]

KeyVault firewalls setup is to allow traffic through selected networks, which is VNET xx-xx-vnet-01-np

If I changed to All Networks it works fine.

If I need to DevOps to go through above VNET where to configure?

Comment: Are you using a private agent or a Microsoft-hosted agent?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a private agent, you'll need to add the subnet containing your private agent to the list of allowed subnets.

If you're using a Microsoft-hosted agent, the best you can do is capture the agent's IP (using something like https://www.ipify.org/) and temporarily add it to the keyvault's IP address whitelist. It's a pain.

Comment: we are using Microsoft Hosted Agent, but for every pipeline run its new IP Address.

Comment: @Sreedhar Exactly. That's why my answer says to use a service like IPify to get the IP address of the agent and temporarily add it to the keyvault's IP address whitelist. You'll have to script it and put it in your pipeline.